# Facing issue to create Cosmos Db using .NET core SDK

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

The code successfully created the container, which is now available for use. However, when attempting to create a database, it enters an infinite loop.

```
var name = "cosmosdb_emulator";
        var exposedPort = 8083; // Port exposed by the container
        var ContainerCosmosServicePort = 8081; // Port used by the Cosmos service within the container

        try
        {
            var containerService = new Builder()
                .UseContainer()
                .WithName(name)
                .UseImage($"mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator")
                .ReuseIfExists()
                .ExposePort(exposedPort, ContainerCosmosServicePort)
               // .WaitForMessageInLog("Cosmos service is successfully listening")
                .Build();                    
           
                containerService.Start();
                Console.WriteLine($"Container {name} started successfully.");

            var _cosmosdbConnectionString = "AccountEndpoint=https://localhost:8083/;AccountKey=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==";

            CosmosClientOptions options = new()
            {
                HttpClientFactory = () => new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
                {
                    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
                })
            };
            // Initialize Cosmos DB client
            CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(_cosmosdbConnectionString, clientOptions: options);

            // Check if the database exists; if not, create it
            DatabaseResponse databaseResponse = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync("abc");
```

Comment: Don't make a habit of hard coding credentials in your source code. Read them from configuration. Sure, _this time_ it was a local emulator, but it's a lot harder to accidentally post your credentials to the internet if they aren't in your source code.

Comment: This is confusing, as a container is stored within a database. If the container is created, then you *have* to have a database already created. Or are you saying you have a *docker container* created? There are docker containers, and there are Cosmos DB containers. Please edit for clarity.

Comment: Here docker container is created

Comment: Is it showing any errors?

Comment: Where is the loop? What are the exceptions/errors you are seeing? If there is a `try`, where is the `catch`?

Comment: @ShashikantNalavade Which package you are using for creating docker container

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

For reference check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-develop-emulator?tabs=docker-windows,csharp&pivots=api-nosql).

For Docker container creation follow this [document](https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet/blob/master/README.md).

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Docker.DotNet;
using Docker.DotNet.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;

namespace CosmosDBConsoleApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main()
        {

            try
            {
                DockerClient client = new DockerClientConfiguration()
                 .CreateClient();

                await client.Images.CreateImageAsync(
                new ImagesCreateParameters
                {
                    FromImage = "mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/windows/azure-cosmos-emulator",
                    Tag = "latest"

                },
                null,
                new Progress<JSONMessage>()) ;

                Console.WriteLine("Image is pulled");

                var container = await client.Containers.CreateContainerAsync(new CreateContainerParameters()
                {
                    Image = "mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator",
                    HostConfig = new HostConfig
                    {
                        PortBindings = new Dictionary<string, IList<PortBinding>>
                            {
                                { "8081", new List<PortBinding> { new PortBinding { HostPort = "8081" } } }
                            },
                            DNS = new[] { "0.0.0.0:8081" }

                   }

                });

                Console.WriteLine("Container created sucessfully");
                await client.Containers.StartContainerAsync(container.ID,
                   new ContainerStartParameters());

                Console.WriteLine("Container started successfully");

                var _cosmosdbConnectionString = "AccountEndpoint=https://localhost:8081/;AccountKey=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==";
                    CosmosClientOptions options = new()
                    {
                        HttpClientFactory = () => new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
                        {
                            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
                        })
                    };

                    // Initialize Cosmos DB client
                    CosmosClient cosmosclient = new CosmosClient(_cosmosdbConnectionString, clientOptions: options);
                                

                    Console.WriteLine("Cosmos client created");

                Database database = await cosmosclient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(
                    id: "cosmosemulatordb",
                    throughput: 400
                );
                Console.WriteLine("Cosmos Database created sucessfully");
                Container dbcontainer = await database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(
                    id: "emulatorcontainer",
                    partitionKeyPath: "/id"
                );

                Console.WriteLine("Cosmos Container created sucessfully");

                var item = new
                {
                    id = "68719518371",
                    name = "Kiama classic surfboard"
                };

                await dbcontainer.UpsertItemAsync(item);

                Console.WriteLine("item created sucessfully");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

### `OUTPUT`:

[image]

```
{
    "id": "68719518371",
    "name": "Kiama classic surfboard"
}
```

[image]

Comment: you are using window's image. My requirement has to create container with Linux image.